# getting multi-level json value

Tags: java, json, object, lambda

In this json, what is the best way to get the object products.

usuly I create All Objects I have in my json return, until i find I whant. But now whant a direct form.

```
Products products = new Products(); 

JsonOrigin jsonOrigin = getJson();
```

getJson() = VALUE --->

```
{"content": {

"date": 1467045042000, "id": 228371,
"volume": [

           { "shipment_order_volume_number": "1",
            "products": [{"id": 13, "sku": "CPM"},{"id": 14,"sku": "QAA"}]
           },
           { "shipment_order_volume_number": "2",
            "products": [{"id": 15, "sku": "AAA"},{"id": 16,"sku": "ABC"}]
           }
         ]
}
}
```

I whan in my products object with the values:

```
[{"id": 13, "sku": "CPM"},{"id": 14,"sku": "QAA"}, {"id": 15, "sku": "AAA"},{"id": 16,"sku": "ABC"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have several POJOs

```
class Content {
    private long date;
    private int id;
    private List<ShipmentOrder> volume;
// getters/setters
}

class ShipmentOrder {
    @JsonProperty("shipment_order_volume_number")
    private int shipmentOrderVolumeNumber;
    private List<Product> products;
// getters/setters
}

class Product {
    private int id;
    private String sku;
// getters/setters
}
```

If you need to collect all products per instance of `Content` as you showed in your example, you may implement the following method:

```
class Content {
    Set<Product> getAllProducts() {
        if (null == volume) {
            return null;
        }
        return volume.stream()
                     .filter (shipment -> shipment.getProducts() != null)
                     .flatMap(shipment -> shipment.getProducts().stream())
                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```